# ELI5: Django Migrations - Do they change the SQL database?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database

My company has tasked me with creating a small proof-of-concept web app where we would like to read and display a few columns from one of our tables in our microsoft sql server. I have set up my django project and installed the django-mssql-backend etc. However I found the explanation of migrations rather vague

> Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema. They’re designed to be mostly automatic, but you’ll need to know when to make migrations, when to run them, and the common problems you might run into. [Django migrations documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/)

I'm **not** allowed to alter the database in any way as it would break some legacy systems so I want to make sure that migrating does not alter the database. Thus my question is rather simple, would executing the "python manage.py migrate" alter the database or is it only locally in my django project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it alters the database.

Since you're working with an existing database, check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/ to ensure your models match exactly.

At the end of the page it says:

> Next, run the migrate command to install any extra needed database records such as admin permissions and content types:

In particular this will create new tables, not alter your own. If adding new tables isn't OK, then don't run the command. However you won't be able to use the built in Django authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't alter the database then you probably want the [inspectdb utiality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) to build models from the exisiting database.